# Navigation Menus missing in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My website is [sfst.org.in](http://sfst.org.in) It has two inbuilt menu options, sub menu and one page menu. I am trying to put the navigation menu at the top but it is not visible on website view. but, when i open the website in mobile, it shows the button to show the navigation menu at the top. Can you please tell me what is wrong in the theme?

Comment: Have you created menus in admin/appearance/menu section ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check you css-file of the theme to see what is in there concerning display on different sizes of the screen. You mentioned that it will be displayed at mobile size but at website size.

Comment: i am not a pro. can you please help me out on this?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to help you when I cannot access all the files. But most of the times the css file has sections. You can take a look at the "menu" or " navigation" section to find out why the menu is shown on mobile and not on the website. Search for something like "@media screen" and take a look at the max and min width.